# FineUploaderBasic for Azure nothing shows up

Tags: azure, fine-uploader

```
            var uploader = new qq.azure.FineUploaderBasic({

                debug: true,
                element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),

                signature: {
                    endpoint: '@Url.Action("GetUploadSASUrl", "Upload")'
                },
                uploadSuccess: {
                    endpoint: '@Url.Action("ProcessImage", "Upload")'
                },
                scaling: {
                    sendOriginal: false,

                    sizes: [
                        { name: "", maxSize: 800 }
                    ]
                },

                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'png']
                }

            });

        </script>
```

Trying to create a FineUploader Basic instance for Azure but nothing shows up. What am I doing wrong?

I've added a debug: true directive but nothing shows up in the console. The initial script tag is there and a div with the id of "fine-uploader-gallery" is there. All the scripts and CSS are on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect something to "show up"? You are using [Fine Uploader's "core" mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/modes/core.html), which assumes you are providing the entire UI yourself and simply making use of the API, options, and events to drive it. If you want to render a default but customizable UI, you should use [UI mode](http://docs.fineuploader.com/modes/ui.html) instead. More information about all of these can be found on the docs site at http://docs.fineuploader.com. Before you go any further, you should spend some time familiarizing yourself with these options.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The documentation is good, but I think it would really help to have a page where there's just a bunch of examples of code on how to accomplish different things. I found this link that got me started right away: http://tellibus.com/fineuploader/fine-uploader-basic-demo.html For me, personally, looking at code is just so much easier than digging through documentation. I'm not trying to say that documentation is not relevant, since good documentation is very important. But code is just a million times more helpful to get started. Thanks,
Mike

Comment: There is a page with a number of live demos + all required code, right on the website. http://fineuploader.com/demos. The page you linked to demonstrates use of a _very_ old version of Fine Uploader. I would recommend not following that.

Comment: Hi Ray, I did look at the demo page, but they all use a template. I wanted to use a basic version, and I didn't see a code example of a basic version. There was this line: var uploader = new qq.FineUploaderBasic({/* options go here .... */}); but then you have to read though all the docs. Just an honest suggestion, provide like 10 more code examples showing off / doing different customizations/ etc. It would help so much. When I got to the demo page, the first feeling I got was a that of a disappointment, "where are more examples"?

Comment: What sort of code example are you looking for? The "core" uploader is the same as the one with the baked-in UI, except you must provide your own UI. The events, API methods, and config options are all the same. So, the API, event, and config examples on the demo page apply to all uploaders.

Comment: With all due respect, the demo page doesn't sell it:( The demos need to be polished up, better colors, a nice stylish progress bar, nice looking buttons, etc. For product like this, and a price you are asking for, things need to look sharp.

Comment: Everything you're asking for here is completely subjective. What might be "nice colors" to some, may be "ugly" to others. The docs and demos clearly show how you can simply update your template to make it _yours_. The demos are neutrally skinned. Now you've moved from lack of demos to a request to improve the colors on the home page. The price of Fine Uploader is not related to the color scheme of the demos. Instead, active feature development, bugfixes, unmatched feature support, and quick response to issues is key here. You haven't made it clear what is missing from the demos or docs

Comment: Well, you could just show off more stuff with code examples. Like in the link I've posted where they show the use of onSumbit, onUpload, onProgress, onComplete, and how it all comes together. This is so helpful. It's true that you could just read the docs and do this yourself, but people are lazy. I want to see things look amazing and work before I read the documentation.

Comment: Understood, and the demo look and feel/styling was very recently updated based on user feedback to look more modern. But again, what looks nice or amazing to one may not look the same to another. So, the style of the demos are consistent with the rest of Fine Uploader's style/theme at the moment, and reflective of the default styling of the UI mode without any additional CSS. I can understand your desire to see the core module used to build a completely custom UI on the demo page, and I will look into putting that together in the near future.

Comment: Ray, if you want, drop me quick e-mail at: "mike smith social 1 at gmail dot com" (no spaces) maybe I can share what I see in my head with you more clearly.

Comment: Mike - I'm sure your thoughts will be useful to other users as well. This in mind, I'd like to discuss further in Fine Uploader's github issue/feature tracker. You can open up a new thread at https://github.com/FineUploader/fine-uploader/issues/new as we can discuss a bit more freeform there.

Comment: Thanks Ray, I will post something in the next few days:)